# How to check if I took an iPhone photo myself?

Tags: iphone, bash

When I import the pictures from my iPhone, they all end up in one huge file list: `IMG_4649.JPG`, `IMG_4650.JPG`, `IMG_4651.PNG`, … There are images I've taken myself, images from friends, images I've downloaded and screenshots I've taken.

I'm looking for a way to programmatically find out whether I've taken a picture myself or not. If the iPhone would store the serial number in the EXIF data I could use that but it doesn't.

Is there any other device specific information stored in the photos? The model alone doesn't help me as others take pictures with the same model.

Comment: This type of information is no where to be found in EXTIF.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about getting that is not available at all.  You cannot track which camera took which photo.  I would open an issue about privacy.

Comment: Only if the phone gives file names in a special way, depending on the source

Comment: I'm not asking about EXIF data. There might be other ways to store device specific information.

Comment: Many cameras store the serial number in the EXIF data. So you usually can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No. As of this writing, the iPhone does not store its serial number in its EXIF data.

---

However, a probabilistic model might work well enough for your purposes.

I would filter out

1. other models (not all your friends and family have the same phone as you)
2. impossible GPS values (from places you've never been, or if you want to get fancy, places you weren't on certain days—just make a table of your locations and correlate with the GPS data in EXIF)

Then, I'd guess that your pictures probably have an aesthetic signature. There's an [interesting paper](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~wangz/project/imsearch/Aesthetics/ECCV06/datta.pdf) on automatically assigning aesthetic scores to photographs. You could filter out photos that don't fall within an expected aesthetic range.

The end result won't be perfect, but will be great motivation to develop a unique photographic style!